# return data from a Promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

I am Relatively a new programmer.
and I am trying to retrieve a specific id value from a promise.
I want a specific value inside this promise, **device.deviceId** , but I am not able to take it out separately and use it in the code.
Tried to use a global variable and assign the value to global variable but since it is asynchronous, not able to update the value.
can someone help?

```
let dev


const videoSelecter = navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
.then(devices => {

devices.forEach(function(device) {

if (device.kind == "videoinput" && device.label=="Doccamera (2b19:0200)") {  
    dev=device.deviceId
   console.log("updated device ID", dev)
   return dev  
}
});
return dev
})
```

dev variable gets me the id but is not able to use it outside this block.

**videoSelecter** returns value

```
> Promise {<pending>}
> __proto__: Promise [[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved" [[PromiseValue]]: "14aa34325245"
```

I am trying to access the value in **[[PromiseValue]]**

Comment: Put all code that depends on the extracted value into a `.then`

Comment: I dont understand. can you please explain?

Comment: See the linked question. `videoSelecter` is populated synchronously, but you need the data that's retrieved asynchronously. Put everything that depends on the asynchronous data in the `.then`, not outside

Comment: I am using the data from this function in another function. is there anyway to retrieve this value and store it and use it later on?

Comment: Yes, consume the Promise in a `.then` in the other function

Comment: Really sorry to ask this. but can you give me a sample?

Comment: Please read the canonical

Comment: i dont understand how to use .then to get that value

Comment: canonical as in?